# freedesktop menus and redundancy of entries

Tags: menu, freedesktop, .desktop

i wanted to create my own menu in xfce, with only the items i needed.
i succeeded with the following code:

```
<Menu>
    <!--find *.desktop files-->
    <DefaultAppDirs />
    <DefaultDirectoryDirs/>

    <Include>
        <Filename>sublime_text.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>xfce-settings-manager.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>exo-web-browser.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>exo-terminal-emulator.desktop</Filename>
        ....
    </Include>

    <Layout>
        <Filename>sublime_text.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>xfce-settings-manager.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>exo-web-browser.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>exo-terminal-emulator.desktop</Filename>
        ....
    </Layout>
</menu>
```

you can see each entry need to be declared two times.
so my question is this: is it possible to somehow ditch the redundancy of having to declare entries two times?
i'm after something like that, for example:

```
<Menu>
    <!--find *.desktop files-->
    <DefaultAppDirs />
    <DefaultDirectoryDirs/> 

    <Layout>
    <Include>
        <Filename>sublime_text.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>xfce-settings-manager.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>exo-web-browser.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>exo-terminal-emulator.desktop</Filename>
        ....
    </Include>
    </Layout>
</menu>
```

if it's not possible, then could you please tell me where can i go to submit this as feature request and discuss freedesktop menu standard with concerned folks ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have found one solution, to have entries declared only once, and keep correct order.
i don't know if this is the best way to do it, but this code below works:

```
<Menu>
    <!--find *.desktop files-->
    <DefaultAppDirs />
    <DefaultDirectoryDirs/> 

    <Include>
        <All/>
    </Include>

    <Layout>
        <Filename>sublime_text.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>xfce-settings-manager.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>exo-web-browser.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>exo-terminal-emulator.desktop</Filename>
        ....
    </Layout>
</menu>
```